# Possible intermediate scales of baryogenesis?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification, scales, baryogenesis

The conventional beyond Standard Model explanation of [baryogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis) is that, within Grand Unified Theories (GUT), there exist some new heavy scalar bosons of mass $M_{\rm GUT}\sim10^{15}$ GeV, which induce baryon number violating processes in the very early Universe. However, in general, baryogenesis could happen at [any time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70034/baryogenesis-only-at-the-planck-scale-or-none-at-all) between the GUT phase transition and the electroweak phase transition at $\Lambda_{EW}\sim 10^2$ GeV.

Are there any specific models which motivate a scale of baryogenesis of around $10^4$ to $10^6$ GeV? I.e. are there any phenomenologically viable baryogenesis models requiring new scalar bosons at such an intermediate mass scale, which induce, e.g., $\Delta B=2$ processes of changing $qqq$ into $\bar{q}\bar{q}\bar{q}$?