# Could the matter-antimatter equivilance paradox be solved by inflation?

Tags: antimatter, cosmological-inflation

At the moment of the Big Bang, matter and antimatter should have been produced in the same amounts. However, we observe only matter and no antimatter leftover from that time. I was thinking that this could be solved by inflation - the same theory which showed how small-scale quantum fluctuations in the beginning led to large-scale structures like galaxies and filaments arising. Could the matter and antimatter actually have been created in equal amounts, but due to quantum randomness, there would be some areas of the universe with a higher rate of matter than antimatter and vice versa, and the initial inflation would have a) expanded those regions to the volume we see today, and b) caused any areas with large amounts of antimatter to be further away from them? If so, then the anthropic principle can easily be used here, because life could only originate in large areas of space where there is only matter or only antimatter. And so the universe *would* have equal amounts of matter and antimatter, but most of the particles would have annihilated each other, and we could only be living in a region where the ratio was too high for that to happen.

Does this solution work, or is there any evidence against it - or flaw in it - that I am not seeing? And if it does work, why have I never seen it proposed elsewhere?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178088/could-the-missing-antimatter-lie-outside-the-observable-universe