# Big bang should have made up an equal amounts of both matter and anti matter, then why don't we see such?

Tags: particle-physics, big-bang, antimatter, matter, baryogenesis

So, my question arises that how do we know that normal matter is more in quantity or number than anti-matter? Research at ALPHA said that anti-matter that the spectrum of hydrogen and anti-hydrogen where exactly the same then how can we say that galaxies far away from us could be made up of normal matter?

They could just have been made up of anti-matter giving out exactly the same spectrum of light as in normal matter galaxies because of which we got trapped into this idea that there is more matter than anti-matter, whereas in reality it could be in equal amounts. And still the probability of having both in equal amount is quite less as experiments at CERN has suggested that number of anti-matter they have produced or received is less than the normal matter. Ok accepted but this ratio of anti-matter to normal matter could be 2:3 or 1:3 and not 1 part per billion. But this experiment largely depends on the axiom stating all anti-atoms will have the same spectrum as their normal matter counterparts.

Again I know this is wrong but why and which experiments contradict it?
Thank you sir/ Madam for your time and reply.

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26397/) may already answer your question.

Comment: There are really two questions here: what the cause for baryon asymmetry is, and how we can tell antimatter-dominant galaxies apart (which is answered in the link above)

Comment: From Dr. Don Lincoln at FermiLab: [Can leptogenesis explain why there's something instead of nothing?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsqEcGMjEfo&list=PLCfRa7MXBEsoJuAM8s6D8oKDPyBepBosS&index=8)

Comment: It would be better to provide links to the source where you found the information.

Comment: Thank you very much sir / ma'am.

Answer (score 1):

> Big bang should have made up an equal amounts of both matter and anti matter,

This is called the [baryogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis) problem for models of the universe based on general realtivity  and the particle [standard model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)

> In physical cosmology, baryogenesis is the physical process that is hypothesized to have taken place during the early universe to produce baryonic asymmetry, i.e. the imbalance of matter (baryons) and antimatter (antibaryons) in the observed universe

So it is a topic under research

> then why don't we see such?

[Here is a link](https://indico.cern.ch/event/849055/contributions/3598247/attachments/1928689/3193869/Leiden2019.pdf) where the observational state of detecting antimatter in the universe is given

Basic tool is that when matter annihilates on antimatter there is electromagnetic radiation characteristic of the annihilation that should be found in gamma ray cosmic detectors as a peak, and there is very little of that observed.

In summary:

The moon is made of matter, because man has walked on it, the sun and planets also because there is no radiation coming specific to annihilation, no comets ever annihilate. The galaxy too has no specific annihilation signal. In the intermediate space between galaxies if one were a matter one and the other antimatter there would be a signal in the space between them of annihilating gas, etc.

Also there are arguments using the uniformity of [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) radiation.

Comment: Thank you ma'am