# Are there entire anti-matter galaxies?

Tags: antimatter, galaxies

Would we be able to tell if an entire neighboring galaxy was made up of anti-matter? What would we see in its signals? It seems like the anti-matter could be stable if it was completely surrounded by other anti-matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Experimental observation of matter/antimatter in the universe](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1165/) and [How would we tell antimatter galaxies apart?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26397/29216)