# Why are we still living if matter and anti-matter annihilate each other?

Tags: antimatter

Everyone knows **matter and anti-matter annihilate each other** . But still do we are alive . How? Is the statement wrong?? I am a layman and a novice to QM but will appreciate a math-free intuitive explanation.

If the antimatters are not around us, where are they???

Comment: related question http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143224/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everyone knows matter and anti-matter annihilate each other . But
>   still do we are alive .

That is simply because there is no antimatter around