# Is it possible there are exotic forms of matter comprised of neutrinos instead of electrons?

Tags: atomic-physics, antimatter, neutrinos

I understand that [ALPHA experiments](http://alpha.web.cern.ch/) revealed that hydrogen and anti-hydrogen atoms have the same spectrum. Is it possible that some galaxies are comprised of extremely similar configurations of matter, except the charges of the subatomic particles are reversed, for example where hydrogen is comprised of: Antiproton + neutron + neutrino? (basically anti-matter galaxies) How would current physics dictate the generated electromagnetic "sphere" of that galaxy react to ours if the sum of the charge was different or it was polarized a certain way and ours was polarized another? How do we have the understanding that all anti-matter destroyed all matter and is there any evidence that the galaxies just have various electromagnetic properties due to their compositions?

Comment: Related, for first question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249459/

Comment: I believe that answer doesn't include any of the conclusive results from the ALPHA experiments.

Comment: Poster may be incorrectly thinking neutrinos are anti-electrons.  An anti-electron is a positron.  Poster please edit if so.

Comment: I believbe you are correct @StephenG, however I thought an anti-electron was  a flavor of neutrino and neutrino was a classification of subatomic particle rather than a specific neutrino (isn't an anti-electron defined as a positron neutrino?)

Comment: Why would the "conclusive results" of ALPHA have any bearing on the answers previously given to antimatter galaxies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would we tell antimatter galaxies apart?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26397/how-would-we-tell-antimatter-galaxies-apart)

Answer (score 1):

The first part

> Is it possible that some galaxies are comprised of extremely similar configurations of matter, except the charges of the subatomic particles are reversed,

is answered in [this question here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26397/how-would-we-tell-antimatter-galaxies-apart). If there existed antimatter galaxies we would have seen them from the annihilations at the interfaces.

The example makes no sense:

> for example where hydrogen is comprised of: Antiproton + neutron + neutrino? (basically anti-matter galaxies)

Hydrogen is made up by a proton and an electron, antihydrogen by an antiproton and a positron ( the [alpha experiment](http://alpha.web.cern.ch/)). Your proposal is unphysical 1) antiproton would annihilate with the neutron, 2) the neutrino interacts only weakly and cannot form bound states.

This makes no sense within astrophysics as we know it:

> How would current physics dictate the generated electromagnetic "sphere" of that galaxy react to ours if the sum of the charge was different or it was polarized a certain way and ours was polarized another?

there is no electromagnetic sphere of a galaxy reacting with another galaxy . Sum of charges also has no physical meaning , and polarization at such distances and sizes also has no meaning.

The title also defies present knowledge of physics:

> Is it possible there are exotic forms of matter comprised of neutrinos instead of electrons?

As I said neutrinos interact only with gravity and the weak interaction and cannot form bound states.

Comment: If the laws of conservation of energy are applied with matter and anti-matter, when they are annihilated they are just being reduced to their constitutant subatomic partics which could theoretically reform in different configurations? How would we determine if different parts of the universe are matter dominated, anti-matter dominated and parts have equal masses or matter and anti-matter?

Comment: If the electromagnetic sphere of one mass is contained within the electromagnetic sphere of another mass, would one magnetic field become Electromagnetically polarized to balance the spheres charge in relation to the two charges of the mass in order to distribute the energy as cohesively as possible?

Comment: It seems to me that you do not read or do not understand the links given to you. You seem to be in a science fiction scenario, not main stream physics so I cannot help you, more so as i do not know your age or physics level. (Your statements would be understandable  for a student  below college age). Sorry , I cannot help you.

Comment: I am assuming it has a law of conservation of energy, and matter is one form of energy, anti-matter is another form of energy. The annihilation of this creates energy as it must be conserved and can then reconstitute or annihilate to smaller fragments when they encounter other subatomic particles? If that is science fiction please help me understand? Is the energy not conserved?

Comment: mainstream physics does not stop at conservation of energy. It assumes as a precondition the standard model of particle physics, as a start for example  http://www.physics.umd.edu/hep/TheStandardModel.pdf  , or https://home.cern/about/physics/standard-model . "fragments" , electromagnetic spheres and such are all your personal constructs and have no contact with mainstream physics. bye bye

Comment: Also please let me know if your statement that this is science fiction includes no conclusive scientific evidence, impossible to be true due to the conclusive evidence presented within observations in behaviors of both small and large quantities or Electromagnetic Energy/Matter/Density of space? I have assumed that quarks and signs of their constituants have been observed within the LHC?

Comment: Also please correct me if I am wrong but the documents you have linkd me to indicate quarks are constituants/fragments of subatomic particles then it has a ? for what they contain and and arrow (Page 4) indicating that it is yet to be discovered. Please also note that the paper is 14 years old: http://www.physics.umd.edu/hep/TheStandardModel.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the question in the title. I tend to think that, theoretically, space objects made of neutrinos should be possible. On the one hand, neutrinos apparently have (very small) mass, so gravity should attract them to each other, on the other hand, neutrinos are fermions, so they should form a degenerate matter at sufficiently high density and sufficiently low energy. Therefore, under appropriate conditions, such objects should neither expand (against gravity) nor collapse (against the Pauli principle). So I don't quite understand @annav's statement: "The title ... defies present knowledge of physics". My reasoning above seems to contradict hers: "neutrinos interact only with gravity and the weak interaction and cannot form bound states"

See also https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.6788 (Abstract: Recent weak and strong lensing data of the galaxy cluster A1689 are modelled by dark fermions that are quantum degenerate within some core. The gas density, deduced from X-ray observations up to 1 Mpc and obeying a cored power law, is taken as input, while the galaxy mass density is modelled. An additional dark matter tail may arise from cold or warm dark matter, axions or non-degenerate neutrinos. The fit yields that the fermions are degenerate within a 430 kpc radius. The fermion mass is a few eV and the best case involves 3 active plus 3 sterile neutrinos of equal mass, for which we deduce 1.51±0.04 eV. The eV mass range will be tested in the KATRIN experiment.)

Comment: Inversely, would that suggest that matter be degenerate if the density of the space was mainly anti-matter based and anti-matter dominated space would generate more stability for anti-matter filled particles?

Comment: @GregGoldberg : With all due respect, your questions suggest that you may need very low-level explanations. I am afraid I don't have time for that, sorry.

Comment: My appologies for suggesting I require that, but from all of my research I have discovered it seems as though matter and energy cannot be destroyed or created, only broken down into smaller parts or reconstituted into bigger formations, everything emits an electromagnetic field where the contents tend to try and equalize based on the total net charge of the sphere of the energy/mass/space within that electromagnetic field, if the field is dense enough with enough layers, it is hard to penetrate the field and that our region of the universe has specific polarities and energy density ratios.