# How do we know that distant galaxies are not made up of antimatter primarily?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, antimatter, galaxies, baryogenesis

This question addresses the first part of my question.  In that it tells us how we would theoretically differentiate antimatter galaxies from regular matter galaxies.

[How would we tell antimatter galaxies apart?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26397/)

[How would one detect antihydrogen in the universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143224/)

[How can we detect antihydrogen?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/590069/)

However I am also interested to know if any experiments have been done to iron out the possibility of some random distant galaxies being made of antimatter.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/590069/123208

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Space isn't a perfect vacuum. Intergalactic matter has very low density, but there is a lot of it. If some galaxies were antimatter, in theory gamma ray astronomers would see matter-antimatter annihilation radiation from their interaction with the intergalactic medium. We don't see it.

Comment: But how do we know that intergalactic medium is made up of matter?

Comment: @Pradyuman at some point there would be a boundary between matter and anti-matter areas. Even if sparse, there would still be a lot of radiation from annihilations.