# How do we know that there is matter-anti-matter asymmetry?

Tags: cosmology, antimatter, galaxies, baryogenesis

It is often said that there's more matter than anti-matter, How do we know that there is more matter,

Can't there be a galaxy made up of antihydrogen? Will that galaxy be any different from ours?

How do we know that there is asymmetry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we know that distant galaxies are not made up of antimatter primarily?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/741936/)

Answer (score 0):

The generally accepted answer to this question is that we're *pretty sure* there are no antimatter galaxies or no large clusters of antimatter, because if they existed, astronomers would see evidence of large flashes of gamma rays from annihilation with inter-galactic gas and dust.

However, we can't prove that there are *no* clusters of antimatter, just argue that it is either extremely rare or such clusters are very small.

We could however, find evidence to support the hypothesis of antimatter galaxies.  Suppose we have an experiment which detects cosmic rays and measures their charges (such as the [Alpha Magnetic Spectrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Magnetic_Spectrometer) experiment ). If we discover an anticarbon nucleus cosmic ray, this could be interpreted as evidence for the existence of an anti-star which fuses antihydrogen and antihelium into heavier anti-nuclei.

Comment: How do we know that there is intergalactic medium made up of matter?