# Proving nearby planets are not antimatter

Tags: astronomy, planets, antimatter, solar-system

Observations of the universe make us think matter is much more common than
antimatter, and I believe no "probably-antimatter planets" have been found.

But, if Pluto, for example, somehow were mainly antimatter, would that
contradict any specific observation?

Is it simply a judgment based on whether we see high-energy photon emissions
(signifying matter-antimatter annihilation) from the planet?  If so, do we
get enough data from Pluto to be confident?

(I'm just curious if Antimatter Pluto could be a believable science fiction movie and can't decide despite answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1165) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26397).)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1165/ and links therein.

Comment: The referenced questions do not answer mine...I made this specifically for Pluto to understand how well we understand our own solar system.  So, I hope this question can be reopened.

Comment: Maybe you should ask why it *can't* (or if it can be) composed of anti-matter.

Comment: The accepted answer to the referenced question says "We're very confident that our local neighborhood is matter, not antimatter".  That seems to be an answer to your question.